# Include, Select, Sort, Limit from multiple models (single query)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to create a single query that includes data from the following tables:

***Conversation**: a model that groups messages between users

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conversation_participants
  has_many :users, :through => :conversation_participants
  ## Attributes title, created_at, updated_at
end
```

---

*** ConversationParticipant**: a model that keeps track of the users of the conversation

```
class ConversationParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## Associations
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
  ## Attributes conversation_id, user_id, seen, created_at, updated_at
end
```

---

*** Message**: a model that keeps track content and sender

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
  ## Attributes sender_id, content, conversation_id, created_at, updated_at
end
```

---

***User**: a model with attribute `name`

---

#### How to get the following in a single query?

> 1. **limit** of (5) recent messages from ***Message*** of uniq ***Conversation***
> 2. **where** `user_id` = current_user.id from ***ConversationParticipant***
> 3. **order** `seen` = `false`, then `updated_at DESC` from ***ConversationParticipant***
> 4. **includes** ***Conversation***
> 5. **includes** (***Message*** sender) => ***User***
> 6. **includes** the other participant from ***ConversationParticipant*** => **User**

---

Note: ***includes*** and ***select*** are important, as this question is meant to reduce the number of queries.

Comment: Would it make sense for Message to have a ConversationParticipant instead of a User?  Also, I'm unclear of what you mean by the Message of uniq Conversation under number 1.  What are you currently using?  Seeing your current queries might help me to understand what it is you are going for.  Also seeing what you expect the returned objects to look like might be helpful too.  Additionally, this might be a good candidate for a database view depending on what you want to do with this information and could greatly simplify the query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here is how I  included all the needed models, this query is translated to 5 sql queries since preload doesn't join (runs in a separate query).

```
Message.joins("LEFT JOIN messages AS m ON messages.id != m.id 
              AND m.conversation_id = messages.conversation_id 
              AND messages.created_at < m.created_at")
       .where('m.id IS NULL')
       .joins("INNER JOIN conversation_participants AS cp 
              ON cp.conversation_id = messages.conversation_id 
              AND cp.user_id = #{user_id}")
       .order("cp.seen, cp.updated_at DESC")
       .limit(5)
       .includes(:sender)
       .includes(conversation: [{conversation_participants: :user}])
```